# Utterance that overlaps with other Alexa skill's invocation word does not work

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

While developing for the Alexa Skills Kit, I ran into the issue where if I have an utterance for my skill that just happens to overlap with the invocation word for a separate skill that I have activated it does not work.

To reproduce this I launch my skill and then say "jeopardy" (I have the Jeopardy skill installed) and Alexa responds with **"I can only help you with one skill at a time"**.  If I want my user to be able to respond to my skill and say "jeopardy" even though I have it listed as one of my utterances they are not able to so.

Just to be clear on my exact interaction, I'm saying "Alexa, launch `my awesome skill`" and then it responds with my message of "How can I help you today?". Now I say "jeopardy" that I have configured as an utterance for my intent it responds with "I can only help you with one skill at a time".

My specific example is for a different invocation word and I'm just referring to the Jeopardy skill as an example.  I've been able to reproduce with multiple skills I'm developing.

Does this mean that as I activate additional skills the available responses to other skills is reduced and if there is an overlap there is nothing I can do?

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything in the Amazon documentation to confirm that this is intended behavior; if you're seeing it in practice, then you may have more luck posting on the Amazon developer forums or something similar to seek specific clarification from Amazon.

Comment: I would agree that this is a bug. There are a few threads about the "I can only help you with one skill at a time" message on the developer forum. Check those out and add your use case to them.

Comment: I was curious and I just tried this with my own skills and I couldn't reproduce it. Can you share more details on what words are you using?

Comment: This was actually fixed by Amazon a while ago based on my feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior, if your utterance is the same as the invocation name of the other skill, this can re-direct requests meant for one of the skills to go to the other if you have both of the skills enabled at the same time. The recommendation would be to pick different utterance, in order to avoid skill overlapping.